# How to sort items coming from text file with ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

Actually I'm working on a class to read a text file that contains the following elements:

```
Ringer-ID-0: USB\Device_Name_Here
Ringer-ID-0: {2344343r4efdwdd2w2sdwq}
Ringer-ID-0: volume =100;
Ringer-ID-0: speaker = off;
Ringer-ID-1: HDAUDIO\Device_Name_Here
Ringer-ID-1: {4r3444ewdwdaedw3re3d34d3}
Ringer-ID-1: volume = 93;
Ringer-ID-1: speaker = off;
Ringer-ID-2: HDAUDIO\Device_Name_Here
Ringer-ID-2: {23edecrrvt5y66h6hyyhy66}
Ringer-ID-2: volume = 93;
Ringer-ID-2: speaker = off;
Ringer-ID-3: HDAUDIO\Device_Name_Here
Ringer-ID-3: {3444444t56756y7h7h6ef}
Ringer-ID-3: volume = 93;
Ringer-ID-3: speaker = off;
Ringer-ID-4: USB\Device_Name_Here
Ringer-ID-4: {r4rfrf54g65g65g6h7uj7}
Ringer-ID-4: volume = 50;
Ringer-ID-4: speaker = on;
```

what I need to do with these elements is to rearrange them in order to have all HDAUDIO devices with its values in the top of my list and USB devices in the bottom like this:

```
Ringer-ID-0: HDAUDIO\Device_Name_Here
Ringer-ID-0: {4r3444ewdwdaedw3re3d34d3}
Ringer-ID-0: volume = 93;
Ringer-ID-0: speaker = off;
Ringer-ID-1: HDAUDIO\Device_Name_Here
Ringer-ID-1: {23edecrrvt5y66h6hyyhy66}
Ringer-ID-1: volume = 93;
Ringer-ID-1: speaker = off;
Ringer-ID-2: HDAUDIO\Device_Name_Here
Ringer-ID-2: {3444444t56756y7h7h6ef}
Ringer-ID-2: volume = 93;
Ringer-ID-2: speaker = off;
Ringer-ID-3: USB\Device_Name_Here
Ringer-ID-3: {2344343r4efdwdd2w2sdwq}
Ringer-ID-3: volume =100;
Ringer-ID-3: speaker = off;
Ringer-ID-4: USB\Device_Name_Here
Ringer-ID-4: {r4rfrf54g65g65g6h7uj7}
Ringer-ID-4: volume = 50;
Ringer-ID-4: speaker = on;
```

I thought first store them in an Array List but I don't know how would be the better way to achieve this, please give a hand, thanks in advance guys

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;



public class RearrangeItems {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("C:\\Users\\John\\Desktop\\items.txt")));
            ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
            String line = reader.readLine();
            while (line != null) {
                list.add(line);
                line = reader.readLine();
            }
            reader.close();
            String[] records = (String[]) list.toArray(new String[] { "" });
            for (int i = 0; i < records.length; i++) {
                System.out.println(records[i]);
            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would better be reading the information to a class and then write your `rearrage` method for a collection of such classes.

```
public class RingerEntry {
    private int ringerID;
    private String ringerType; //USB | HDAUDIO
    private String ringerName; //device name
    private String hwID; // whatever is within { and }
    private int voluem;
    private boolean speakerStatus;
}
```

Write getters and setters for this. Then create an `ArrayList` of these and write a `rearrange()` function to take the list as argument and return a sorted one. You can simple sort the elements of the list based on the `ringerType` field. This will get all your `HDAUDIO` devices on top and `USB` devices will be pushed to bottom.

Good Luck!